# What did the study plan of a early 20th century mathematics undergraduate program look like?

Tags: mathematics, mathematics-social-history, education, academia

I am interested in what subjects and activities mathematics undergrads were involved in the beginning of the 20th century. Most subjects mathematics majors study at an intermediate and advanced level now were relatively recently developed (for example, Measure Theory or Modern Logic). How different is an early 20th century mathematics undergraduate from a 21st century mathematics undergraduate?

Comment: Perhaps specify a location.  I think "major" is a US notion?  This signifies undergraduate study?

Comment: I agree about location. Also, because the teaching of mathematics in Europe/France may be very different from the US.

Comment: How different was mathematics higher education in Europe from that in other parts of the world?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example.
link https://iiif.lib.harvard.edu/manifests/view/drs:467220382$1i

Official Register of Harvard University
Volume VI, May 26, 1909, number 16
Announcement of the Courses of Instruction offered by the
Faculty of Arts and Sciences, 1909-1910

mathematics on pages 84--88

[image: cover]
[image: 84]
[image: 85]
[image: 86]
[image: 87]
[image: 88]
[image: 89]